# Why can I still hear Chrome notification on my laptop even when it's sleeping?

Tags: laptop, sleep

If I put my laptop to sleep, I goes to sleep without problem (screen turns dark, music stops playing, power LED pulses, etc.).

But I can still hear Chrome notification sound constantly. Also when I move the mouse the screen turns on instantly (without any delay at all).

This makes me suspicious that the laptop is not actually sleeping. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, my laptop has a feature called Connected Standby enabled. I followed these steps to disable it:

- Start the registry editor (regedit.exe).
- Move to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power.
- Double-click CsEnabled and set to 0, then click OK.
- Restart

After this, the laptop can enter "deep" sleep, so no more notification sound while sleeping and there's a bit of delay when waking up (about 1s).

Comment: If Windows has decided to activate this feature _by default_, that hopefully means your laptop CPU's "idle standby" mode (S0ix) is sufficiently low-power that it shouldn't be all that much of a downgrade from the usual "deep sleep" (S3) mode, and it probably even has been certified for that.

Comment: Do note the warning at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby that Microsoft doesn't support switching between these two modes without an OS reinstall. (Although I have no idea why that would be the case.)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone findind this now, Microsoft removed that registry key and GUI other settings for this.

You can find a detailed but easy to read post here:

https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-modern-standby-network-connectivity-in-windows-11.3286/#option2

Archived URL (in case the OG site goes down):
https://web.archive.org/web/20220729100223/https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-modern-standby-network-connectivity-in-windows-11.3286/

If I copy-pasted anything from that article here, I would do everyone a disservice.